# Partial application in Scala not referentially transparent?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Given two functions:

```
def f(a: String, b: Int): Int = a.length + b
val g: Int => String = _.toString
```

why is it that I can compose a partially applied `f` with `g` by means of an intermediate assignment:

```
val f_ = f(_: String, 42)
f_ andThen g
// String => String = <function1>
```

but not directly:

```
f(_: String, 42) andThen g
// error: value andThen is not a member of Int
```

Is this a problem with the type inferencer or somehow expected behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a syntactic error, if you turn on `-Xprint:parser` option you'll see the difference between your expression and the correct one, i.e: `(f(_: String, 42)) andThen g`.

Your expression:

```
((x$1: String) => f((x$1: String), 42).andThen(g))
```

The correct one:

```
((x$1: String) => f((x$1: String), 42)).andThen(g)
```

You can see the difference. It happens because of expansion rule, scalac first normalise syntax to the dot form and then expand it. The same rule applies to this form of function application: `func(_)` which is expanded to the inner-most braces, I don't remeber where in SLS it's written.